# v-for with varaible number of content blocks

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to have variable amount of content blocks inside a v-for loop? Say one of the instances has 1 content paragraph and an other needs 3 content paragraphs? Would you have to create a nested loop inside the outer loop?

https://codepen.io/mDDDD/pen/dyWRqJW

```
  <div id='timeline' class="timeline container">
                <div class="timeline__main">
                  <div
                    class="timeline__main--inner"
                    v-for="year in timelines"
                    :key="year.id"
                    ref="timelines"
                  >
                    <div class="timeline-title">
                      <h3 class="title-3">{{ year.year }}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline-content">

        **(one of the instances this needed 3 P tags with class history content?)**

                      <p class="history-description">
                        {{ year.content }}
                      </p>


const Timeline = {
  data() {
    return {
       timelines: [
        { id: 2020, year: '2020', content: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. `},
        { id: 2019, year: '2019', content: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. ` },
      ],
    };
  },
 
};

Vue.createApp(Timeline).mount("#timeline");

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: you can but again you should be able to identify it from the dataset over which you are iterating....and based on that you can load the template accordingly

Comment: How would it be determined if it needs a specific amount of paragraphs?

Comment: so then how do you expect it get automatically rendered?

Comment: one way is you can have line breaks in the string like </br>

Comment: You need "something" to dictate new rows need to be added. For instance, imagine it comes from your data `{ id, year, content, stuff: ["a", "b"] }` . Now you'd just loop over the 'stuff' array with a v-for as you have already done for your timelines. Here is an example: https://codepen.io/KingKozo/pen/jOmwvgN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two adjustments: (1) to the data, representing N paragraphs per year, and (2) the important one in the markup, nesting a v-for to iterate the nested array.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      timelines: [{
          id: 2020,
          year: '2020',
          content: [`The first paragraph in 2020`, `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. `]
        },
        {
          id: 2019,
          year: '2019',
          content: [`The first paragraph in 2019`, `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. `]
        },
      ],
    };
  },
})
```

```css
.timeline__main--inner {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.timeline__main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 785px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 65px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
  h3 {
    color: green;
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}

.timeline-content {
  padding: 15px 54px 15px 62px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <div id='timeline' class="timeline container">
    <div class="timeline__main">
      <div class="timeline__main--inner" v-for="year in timelines" :key="year.id" ref="timelines">
        <div class="timeline-title">
          <h3 class="title-3">{{ year.year }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="timeline-content">
          <p class="history-description" v-for="(p,i) in year.content" :key="i">
            {{ p }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```